# what is the approximate average time required to create a new web application in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, central-administration

We have quad core 3.2ghz 16gb ram i5 machine.

On this vm workstation is installed. Settings->

12gb ram

2 processors (1 core per processor)

SharePoint 2013 is installed on this vm.

It takes approximately 6mins to create a new web application.  Is this ideal time? Or is there less resource allocation done on vm.?

Comment: Sounds quite normal, but your specs are in the lower range for a single server running all sp processes and db(?). But creating web applications should not be something you do that often?

Comment: Yes. Sql and sp on samr machine. Ok. Web app creation is not often. But it must be effecting any other sp module